# How to load facebook JS SDk in the jQuery block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

According to Facebook: "The best place to put this code is right after the opening  tag"

Example:

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelURL : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

But I would like like to add this in the jquery block `$(document).ready(function() { }`

How can that be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include jQuery, and then...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    callFB();
    loginClick(); // Call function
});

function callFB(){
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
        channelURL : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));     


}

function loginClick(){
   // your click handling code in here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Where would I add something like this: `$("#Facebook_Button").click(function(event) { FB.login(function(response) { });`  and also for `FB.getLoginStatus()`

Comment: add a new function within the document.ready, so loginClick() then create another function with your code within in same form as above

Comment: Shouldn't `loginClick()` function be in the callFB() function?

Comment: The loginClick() function could be initialised in either the callFB function or in the doc ready statement.

The jQuery.click() will only run after a click, so will be after the page loads and this scripts executes

Comment: Facebook added a tutorial on how to integrate the API with JQuery 2.0 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery

Answer (score 2):

This is more what you're looking for I think...
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this jQuery plugin i made too.. :]

```
jQuery.fbInit = function(app_id) {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : app_id, // App ID
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));

    $('<div />').attr('id','fb-root').appendTo('body');
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fbInit('12345678901234');
});
```